# Python, extracting key aspects from consumer reviews

Tags: python, text, nltk

I have a data set of consumer reviews. From these reviews I will like to extract most frequently occurring aspects. The process I am applying includes 

 - Step 1: Tokenizing reviews into sentences

- Step 2: Tokenizing sentences into words after basic NLP pre-processing. Pre-processing removes punctuation and English stop words. 

- Step 3: Pos_tagging and extracting all words with pos tag of 'NN','NNP','NNS','NNPS'

- Step 4: Combining all the words across all reviews to find the most frequently occuring words 

- Step 5: Using top 40 terms as my aspects

Is this a good approach or do you recommend doing something different?

Comment: Yes... its good approach..And extract JJ and JJR(plural sentence) from statement related to that aspect  to analyse the sentiment for that aspects..

Answer (score 0):

yes .. but u need to specify aspects by yourself by choosing the most essential specification for the product